# Is there any definition of a "friend" in Islam?

Tags: friendship

I am a 28 years old male and I am a Muslim. For a long time, I was thinking about what makes someone a "friend". In Islam, is there any definition or criteria to define someone as a "friend"? If yes, what is the definition/criteria?

Comment: Friend is a culture related term in Islam you may rather speak about companion or good company.